# Can I use a Bluetooth headset with my Windows desktop/laptop for Skype or other VOIP applications?

Tags: windows-7, windows, skype, bluetooth, voip

Can I use a Bluetooth headset with my Windows desktop/laptop for Skype or other VOIP applications?

I am considering purchasing a [MOTOROLA H730](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16875982368)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you may need to install the third-party Bluetooth stack that came with the dongle or machine in order to use it as a normal audio device.

Comment: why?  please elaborate.